# If a panicked creature is prevented from moving, do they cower?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, movement

> If cornered, a panicked creature cowers.

What counts as "cornered"? If a panicked creature tries to flee, and gets immobilized by Stand Still, does it then count as cowering (assuming it doesn't have a way to move without move actions)?

Answer (score 10):

This is unclear; “cornered” doesn’t have a game-term definition, and so we have to just use our own understanding of the English text here. As such, what follows is my opinion and what I have used at my table.

No, Stand Still doesn’t prevent the creature from moving more than momentarily. Such a creature would immediately begin trying to continue moving—which they can’t until their next turn, but remember that “turns” are a game abstraction. In-character, the panicked creature is only stopped for a moment—a few seconds, at most. That character is trying to get themselves together and continue moving as soon as possible. They haven’t given up on movement. There is no reason they would cower.

On the other hand, if you apply a longer-lasting immobilization effect, cowering is likely how they would spend their time, yes.

Answer (score 1):

> What counts as "cornered"?

This isn't specified, but I've interpreted it this way; a panicked (or turned) creature is cornered if the creature must move closer to the source of the fear to get away. As long as they could maintain at least their initial distance and avoid moving any closer to get to an exit, they could flee, otherwise they cower.

> If a panicked creature tries to flee, and gets immobilized by Stand Still, does it then count as cowering (assuming it doesn't have a way to move without move actions)?

That's tough. Cowered is technically a worse condition than panicked, since it incurs more penalties, so I would be hesitant to apply it here and there really are no guidelines for how denial of movement translates to "cornered". You could rule either way, but I think I would not apply further penalties unless the creature felt like it was cornered.